# Closure as argument in Jenkins shared library function

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-shared-libraries

let's say I have a Configuration class in a Jenkins shared library written like this

```
class Configuration {
    String param1, param2
    Closure closure1
}
```

There's also a helper class like this

```
class Helper {
   
   String helperMethod(String arg1, Closure closure1) {
       // some invocation to closure 1
   }

}
```

Within the var folder there's a dynamic pipeline in a `pipeline.groovy` file like this:

```
def call(Configuration config) {
    node {
        stage {
            def helper = new Helper()
            helper.helperMethod('foo') { config.closure1 it }
        }
    }
}
```

Finally I'm trying to use the shared library in another repo like this,

```
@Library('my-library')
import com.mylibrary.configuration.Configuration 

def baz = { it.toUpperCase() }
def config = new Configuration(
    param1: 'foo', 
    param2: 'bar',
    closure1: baz
)

pipeline(config)
```

The problem is that `baz` get transformed to `org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsClosure2` and `helperMethod` throws a `MissingMethodException` because of the type mismatch between `CpsClosure2` and the expected `groovy.lang.Closure`

I've tried:

- Using the `@NonCPS` annotation in `baz`
- Strong typing the closure through a functional interface and trying to pass it to the config like `closure1: baz as MyStronglyTypedClosure`
- Removing the closure typing in the `helperMethod` definition
- Using `helper.helperMethod('foo', config.closure1)` instead of `helper.helperMethod('foo') { config.closure1 it }`

to no avail :(

Is there any workaround to receive the closure in the configuration so it can be used correctly in the helper class? Thanks in advance

Comment: CpsClosure2 extends standard groovy closure: https://javadoc.jenkins.io/plugin/workflow-cps/org/jenkinsci/plugins/workflow/cps/CpsClosure2.html there is another issue. please provide full error.

Comment: could you add stacktrace and the error message please?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help guys, indeed it worked, it was an invocation parameter mistake

Answer (score 0):

`MissingMethodException` is usually thrown when you are invoking functions incorrectly or inexistent function, it rarely has to do with CPS closures, which indeed as dagget mentioned, extends standard java closures. I strongly recommend you to use testing frameworks like Spock (with Jenkins extension) to be able  to detect errors beforehand.